# Event Listeners for transparent Images on ActionScript 3.0 for iOS development

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, events, transparent, touch-event

This one is for an iOS app built on Flash Air for iOS - AS3.0.

I have few transparent objects on my screen and all of them should respond to the touch event.
The requirement is to click through the transparent area of an object to hit the one behind it. Any help is really appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it! Sharing for people in need!

```
import com.mosesSupposes.bitmap.InteractivePNG;

this.$loader = new Loader();
this.$loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, _loaded, false, 0, true);
this.$loader.load(new URLRequest("a.png"));

function _loaded($e:Event) {
    $e.target.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, _loaded);
    var $png:InteractivePNG = new InteractivePNG();
    var $mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip()

    $png.addChild($e.currentTarget.loader.content);
    $mc = this.addChild($png) as MovieClip;

    $mc.alphaTolerance = 0;

    $mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _clicked, false, 0, true);
}
function _loadComplete() {
    trace("Load Complete");
}
function _clicked($m:MouseEvent) {
    trace("Clicked ",$m.currentTarget.name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your image are bitmaps that's not possible. Think about the transparent areas as a clear sheet of acetate covering whatever is beneath.

Comment: Thanks crooksy88! They are bitmaps and the program demands that! I have read somewhere that it is doable for a desktop app; no clue about the mobile apps though!

Comment: Here we go! http://dougmccune.com/blog/2007/02/03/using-hittestpoint-or-hittest-on-transparent-png-images/